# Algorithm used to split CSV into multiple chunks? Is it possible to split a CSV without reading line by line?

Tags: algorithm, csv

I need to know whether a large CSV file can splited into chunks without processing line by line? if yes, then please explain.

All answer suggests tools to split into chunk but i need to know about the working?

Example:
Consider The sample.csv file contains 100 rows. now i need 10 csv file each has 10 rows with file name as sample1.csv,sample2.csv......sample10.csv

To do this whether we need to load the sample.csv file to the memory(or we can get it as stream) and then after reaching the 11th record create a new sample2.csv write the next 10records to new file? Is there any other way other than reading the records one by one? refer the below pseudo code to understand better.

pseudo code:

```
File file = new FileReader("sample.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String st;
FileWritter fw; 
int i=0;
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
    if(i%10==0){
       //flush and close previous filewritter then 
       //create a new file and write the upcoming records in new file.
       //fw = new FileWritter("sample"+i).
    }
    fw.write(st);
    i++;
  }
```

I need to know is there any way to avoid reading the whole csv file to split it into chunks?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand your question. What do you mean with "without processing line by line"?

Comment: Read _n_ bytes, write to `chunk1`, read next _n_ bytes, write to `chunk2`. Please, elaborate.

Comment: @DaemonPainter i have edited the question with sample pseudo code. can you able to understand now?

Answer (score 1):

If you *need 10 csv file each has 10 rows* then you need to read 10 rows and write them. But instead you could read *n* bytes + up to the next newline (or however you define a row), write that to a chunk file, rinse and repeat.

Here is a sample GNU awk code to read 1024 bytes + the rest of the line (**Notice: files named `file` and `chunk1` - `chunk8` will be created to the cwd**):

```
$ cat splitter.awk
BEGIN {
    RS=".{1024}"                 # abusing record separator to read 1024 bytes
}
NR%2 {                           # for every odd record (1,3, ...)
    buffer=RT                    # RT holds the 1024 bytes
    if(RT=="")                   # last block is below 1024 bytes
        buffer=$0                # ... so saving the day
    RS="\n"                      # for next round we read up to newline
    next                         # to the even round
}
{                                # for every even record (2,4, ...)
    file="chunk" ++c             # naming the  chunk files
    print buffer $0 > file       # output to the chunk file
    close(file)                  # better close it 
    buffer=""                    # probably futile
    RS=".{1024}"                 # set the record separator for next, odd round
}
END {                            # handling the less-than-1024-bytes chunk
    if(buffer) {
        file="chunk" ++c
        printf buffer > file
    }
}
```

Make a test file (299 lines of csv):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";while(++c<300)print c,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}' > file
```

Run the `splitter.awk`:

```
$ gawk -f splitter.awk file
```

Result:

```
$ ls -l chunk*
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1047 Oct  3 17:00 chunk1
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1032 Oct  3 17:00 chunk2
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1038 Oct  3 17:00 chunk3
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1025 Oct  3 17:00 chunk4
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1025 Oct  3 17:00 chunk5
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1025 Oct  3 17:00 chunk6
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1025 Oct  3 17:00 chunk7
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  150 Oct  3 17:00 chunk8
```

**Update:** Updated version for GNU awk (uses `stat()` function in `filefuncs` extension) which allows you to specify the number of chunks to split to:

```
$ cat splitter2.awk
@load "filefuncs"
BEGIN {
    if(n=="")                    # if no chunk number is given
        n=10                     # use 10
    filename=ARGV[1]             # get the filename from the argument list
    if(stat(filename, fdata)<0)  # try to get the file size
        exit                     # exit if no such file
    size=int(fdata["size"]/n)    # calculate the chunk size
    close(filename)            
    RS=".{" size "}"             # abusing record separator to read n bytes
}
NR%2 {                           # for every odd record (1,3, ...)
    buffer=RT                    # RT holds the n bytes
    if(RT=="") {                 # last block is below n bytes
        file="chunk" ++c         # name the last chunk file
        printf $0 > file         # output the last chunk
        exit                     # exit so that other files cant be processed
    }
    RS="\n"                      # for next round we read up to next newline
    next                         # to the even round
}
{                                # for every even record (2,4, ...)
    file="chunk" ++c             # naming the  chunk files
    print buffer $0 > file       # output to the chunk file
    close(file)                  # better close it 
    RS=".{" size "}"             # set the record separator for next, odd round
}
```

Run it with:

```
$ gawk -v n=3 splitter2.awk file
$ ls -l chunk*
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 2467 Oct  4 08:44 chunk1
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 2475 Oct  4 08:44 chunk2
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 2425 Oct  4 08:44 chunk3
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no it is not possible to process a CSV file without reading it line by line, because a CSV file is not fixed-width. Unless... your particular case allows you to cheat :)

For example, if you want to skip to the nth record to create "a chunk", you would have to know the file offset where that record is located. With the offset on hand, you'd be able to jump to that specific offset in the file, without reading any lines before that offset. But with a CSV file it's not possible to know what the offset is because the records can be of different lengths. Unless...

... your records happen to be fixed-length. If so, the offset is generally something like: `n * RECORD_LENGTH` In other words, to jump to the nth record you'd multiply n times the length of the records, to get the offset.

In short, while generally it's not possible to process a CSV file without reading it line by line, you may be able to utilize characteristics of the files you're processing to come up with an algorithm to processes the files more efficiently.